# Order of objects in JSON after modification

Tags: apache-nifi

For example I've a JSON looks like:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "price":400
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "price":500
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "price":250
   }
]
```

If I use JSON content modification processors (**QueryRecord, JoltTransformJson, Groovy scripts**, etc), is the **order of the objects in JSON guaranteed**? For example I'll use simple JOLT:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "status": 0
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Objects inside JSON still will have same order or something like this can happen?

```
[ {
  "id" : 3,
  "price" : 250,
  "status" : 0
},{
  "id" : 1,
  "price" : 400,
  "status" : 0
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "price" : 500,
  "status" : 0
} ]
```

Comment: As per my knowledge, the Order will be the same. it does not change.

Comment: Hi default wont change the order.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the order will remain. To test out how the JOLT will look, you can use this JOLT Transform Online demo https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception What it shows is that the order should remain after the JOLT transform